# cannot remote connect to azure windows server from mac

Tags: azure, ssh, azure-virtual-machine, rdp, azure-virtual-network

I am connecting to an Azure Windows server for the first time, using either RDP or ssh. I have made similar connections to aws ec2 before with no problem.

So far I have checked

1. network security group allows both 22 and 3389
2. the associated NSG inbound rules allows 22 and 3389
3. cleared the domain field in RDP dialogue as stated in http://shebangme.blogspot.com/2010/05/remote-desktop-connection-cannot-verify.html

Still, no connections by either RDP nor ssh. What else is there to check please?

Comment: SSH connection is for Linux VM. Can you SSH to linux VM? Is this issue to one specific windows VM or you cannot RDP or SSH to all VMs on Azure ?

Comment: There was a comment to try installing RDP from app store. That solution worked. I wonder what happened to that response. as for ssh. It does seem ssh should only be good for linux, but then why does the azure connection dialog provide instructions to do ssh?

Comment: It's just connection feature. You can choose the right way to connect your VM. Also, Azure will direct you to choose the right connection way by default.